# Adding a composer package to my Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

- I'm trying to add the "cedarmaps-php-sdk" composer package to my Laravel project

the package can be found here: https://github.com/cedarstudios/cedarmaps-php-sdk

- I have successfully installed the package using

  > composer install 
  >   &
  >   composer update
- The problem is when I want to use the 'CedarMaps' I get the error:

  `"main(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')"` [*image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30770127/57369349-8ca86e80-71a2-11e9-9231-e893b46ad8f3.png)
- for now, I'have manually bypassed this problem by changing

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');
```

to

```
require('../vendor/autoload.php');
```

in the below file (the repository file)

> vendor/cedarmaps/cedarmaps-php-sdk/src/CedarMaps.php

am I doing anything wrong?

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Let me ask a *question*: Was that necessary for this package to require autoload.php itself
, I mean doesn't composer handle this autoloading for all packages automatically?

Comment: Where you use `CedarMaps`? Can you share it?

Comment: `use CedarMaps\CedarMaps;` and then
`new CedarMaps($access_token);`

this seems to work fine since the error is thrown from inside the package's file itself

`\vendor\cedarmaps\cedarmaps-php-sdk\src\CedarMaps.php`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `composer require 'package name'` to install a package to your existing project then do a `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: I have run this 'composer dump-autoload' to regenerate the autoload before.
and there is an autoload.php file in my vendor folder

Comment: Firstly undo all the changes you made to your `vendor/autoload.php` you just need to do above two steps, then you can simply use the class `$cedarMaps = new \CedarMaps\CedarMaps('$api_key');` in your controller.

Comment: composer dump-autoload will include all the new packages that are added and make them available to your project through class map. you don't need to change anything.

Comment: also to get the api key you'll need to make a curl or guzzle request from method itself.

Comment: In fact, I have done no changes in my autoload.php nor the composer.json
but I had first run `composer require cedarmaps/cedarmaps-php-sdk` which will update my composer.json and add new `require "cedarmaps/cedarmaps-php-sdk" :  "^2.0"`

Comment: I didn't get your mean by `Firstly undo all the changes you made to your vendor/autoload.php`
but simply following your suggestion in comments and reply. no, it didn't help

Comment: may i know how you are calling your class CedarMaps?

Comment: try `require(_DIR_.'vendor/autoload.php');`

Comment: I) I have commented that in the first post
II) I have tried it before and it causes the same error